# Bounded linear operator can be a locally essentially bounded function?

Tags: operator-theory

We know that, a bounded linear operator, is a linear transformation $L:H\rightarrow H$ on Hilbert space $H$ such that
$$\|Lv\| \le M \|v\|, \ \ \ (M>0, v\in H)$$
A bounded linear operator is generally not a bounded function. Rather, a bounded linear operator is a [locally bounded function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_boundedness).

Perhaps not in general but, at least for a particular space, bounded linear operator can be a locally essentially bounded function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard measure assigned on infinite-dimensional spaces. So the concept of "essentially bounded" is undefined in general.

Comment: Thank you! This would change for finite-dimensional space?

Comment: In that case any linear operator is continuous and locally bounded, no need to introduce any measure theory.